# ODBC: Which server to configure it on?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm needing to create/configure an ODBC connection, but I'm a little fuzzy on the where. My goal is for an SSIS package to extract the data from an Access file and populate a SQL table on a recurring (daily) basis.

Here's my scenario:

Server 1 contains a program that populates and maintains an MS Access DB file. This file is the raw data source I need for populating a SQL table via SSIS.

Server 2 is the server that houses my SQL installation.

Which server do I need to configure ODBC on? Based on the MS documentation, I'm not sure if it should be where the Access file is, or if it should be where the SQL/SSIS lives.

Comment: You need to drivers installed on what ever server is trying to access the data. You haven't described what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: Well, I suppose that would be Server 2 then, as it's the SQL/SSIS there that needs to get to the Access file elsewhere.

Comment: I would say both. Server 1 needs an ODBC connection configured to access the MS Access DB file so that it can populate and maintain its contents. Server 2 also needs an ODBC connection configured so that SSIS can access the MS Access DB file to read the data in. Be aware: both servers should not access the same MS Access DB file at the same time.